# Clousure code won't execute wrapped in a function

Tags: swift, closures

I have a closure making a http call wrapped in a function which is called from the click of a button. However when I debug I can see the code within the closure never executes, the programme jumps out of the function altogether when it reaches the closure.

```
func getTheForeCast(city: String) {
    println("Function  getForecast city passed = : \(city)")

    var webAddress: String = "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/\(city)/forecasts/latest"

    println("Web address url : \(webAddress)")

    let url = NSURL(string: webAddress)
    println(url!)

// PROGRAM EXITS FUNCTION HERE

    let openbrowserSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) in   
        // in the following code, session returns data, error, and response
        println("In closure")

        if error == nil {
            // no errors, convert html to readable data
            var urlConverted = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            println(urlConverted)

            // run this asynchronously using a grand central dispatch 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.webview_displayWeather.loadHTMLString(urlConverted, baseURL: nil) } // dispatch

        } else if error != nil {
            println("Error loading page")
            println(error.description)    
        }           
    } // closure
} // func
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: The debugger is not that stable with Swift as it should be. Have you tried a `println` to verify your observation?

Comment: Yes nothing prints to console within the closure code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks created by `NSURLSession` are initially in the "suspended" state.
You have to call `resume()` after creating the task:

```
let openbrowserSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data, response, error) in

    // ...

}
openbrowserSession.resume()
```

otherwise nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong signature. Use

```
func dataTaskWithURL(_ url: NSURL,
   completionHandler completionHandler: ((NSData!,
                              NSURLResponse!,
                              NSError!) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```